# Access rails params hash in jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to access Rails params hash in jquery? I need to add one more key(which is nothing but a column in the table) to params before submit of a form.

```
$('#form_id').submit(function() {
        // do some manipulation to get key
        params[key] = value;
        // params in rails hash 
        $('#form_id').submit();
 });
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign the value of a param to a variable in JavaScript, but you'll need to be sure to [escape the param](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) to prevent possible XSS attacks.

```
<script>
  var key = "<%= j(params['key']) %>";
</script)>
```

...but you probably don't need to use JavaScript. If you're trying to submit one of the params along with the form, you can easily pass it using a hidden form element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="column" value="<%= j(params['key']) %>">
```

This will result in `param[:column]` being set to the given param value upon form submission.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

Just add that jQuery code to your template and call params like this. I don't know what do you want to do exactly so I just show how to access the params hash.

*Haml* version:

```
:javascript
  console.log "#{j params[:key]}";
```

*ERB* version:

```
console.log "<%= j params[:key] %>";
```

Comment: This will expose you to potential XSS attacks... don't do it.

Comment: @faraz I agree this technique must be handled with care, input should be checked for potential attacks and so on. But still, it's a technique at hand and its a correct answer to the question ;)